# Has anyone tried the trac to fogbugz conversion/import tool?

Tags: import, trac, fogbugz, data-importer

http://our.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W977

I suspect it will be a simple task, but just thought I would ask before I tried it.

If you have used it, how did it go?  Any caveats or things to help?  Can the changes be undone automatically?

Anything you would have done differently or configured in trac beforehand to make it go easier?

By the way:
I am pleased with my initial trial of fogbugz,  Nothing wrong with trac, but I really wanted an autoresponder and a way for emails to support@mycompany.com to create a new ticket and reply.  It is just so professional.

Curious about the project estimation, but that was not a factor.  I am looking forward to trying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it and it choked on our Wiki pages. I wasn't particuarly excited about the way the import tool mapped the Trac fields to the FogBugz fields.

Another issue is that you can't really delete issues once they're in FogBugz, so after the first failed import I just closed my Student & Startup account and opened a new one.

I ended up transferring our ~100 bugs manually because I decided too many of them were stale and it was worth the time it took to personally look at each one and rethink the priority. If you have more bugs or aren't at a point in your project where stepping back and looking at the whole To-Do list in that way would make sense, that might not be an option.

All that said: I'm loving FogBugz. The fact that our users and testers are getting confirmation emails with links to their tickets is forcing us devs to be more responsive to incoming requests, and the email tools make it easy to have a conversation about each issue. In my case, the import pain was worth it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not surprised.  I love the confirmation emails as well and i will just hand-create the stuff I have in trac.  There are not that many.